# Prime element in ring without unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, divisibility

Definitions of prime element:

$(1)$ We say $p$ is prime if $p|ab$ it implies $p|a$ or $p|b$ (I don't need definition of unity here)

$(2)$ We say $p$ is prime if $p=ab$ it implies $p|a$ or $p|b$ (I don't need definition of unity here)

Are these two definitions equivalent?

Note: $p = ab$ it may not imply $p|ab$ using definition $(1)$ (as much as I can see because there is no unity)

Motivation: ring without unity with an prime element $p$ such that $ab=p$ but $p$ does not divide $a$ nor it divides $b$ (if possible)

Comment: If $p|a$ or $p|b$ then WLOG say $p|a$ i.e. $a=pr$, then $ab=p(rb)$ so certainly with your definition $p=ab$ implies $p|ab$

Comment: @AdamHughes but you start with assumption p/a or p/b. What if we don't know intially p/a or p/b

Comment: That's because you said that was your definition of a prime element.

Comment: @AdamHughes Yes if p/ab but p=ab does not imply p/ab

Comment: Yes it does, according to your definition, if $p$ is prime, then $p|a$ or $p|b$, hence $p|ab$ by my argument above

Comment: @AdamHughes I am not saying you are wrong. But I want a and b such that p = ab but p doesn't divide a nor b(if possible) You are doing converse of statement as much as I can see

Comment: Sushil, that's impossible. The one inviolate thing in all mathematics is the definition. You are asking for something which is simultaneously prime and not prime. By the law of the excluded middle, this is impossible.

Comment: I don't think I am finding example which is prime as well as not prime. I just have two different definition. And I am looking whether these are equivalent or not.  There is no violation of law of excluded middle

Comment: @AdamHughes I have modified the question, may be this will help you in explaining things to me

Answer (score 0):

An example where (1) and (2) are not equivalent is the Rng $2\mathbb{Z}$.

If we take definition (1), then 2 is not prime since if $a=b=6$, we have $ab=36$ and $2|36$ since $36=2\times 18$.  However 2 does not divide 6 in $2\mathbb{Z}$ as we cannot write $6=xy$ where $x,y\in 2\mathbb{Z}$.

On the other hand 2 is prime according to (2) since the condition holds vacuously.

Comment: Very correct thanks but may I ask one more question. p=ab where p prime but ring without unity would it imply p/a or p/b

Comment: @Sushil - I assume by prime, here you mean your definition (1). In that case the answer is yes.  If $p=ab$ then in particular $p|(ab)(ab)$ and hence $p|ab$ by definition (1) since $p$ is assumed to be prime.  Again, since $p$ is prime we then have $p|a$ or $p|b$.